# Unpacking arguments: how to stop a list from turning to a nested list

Tags: python, list, function, sorting, argument-unpacking

I have created a function called `other_func` that results in a list, for example: `[12,322,32]`

I want to create a function that will receive the other function and it will sort this list. I want to use `*args` as seen below, to better understand how it works:

```
def biggest_gap(*args):
    result = sorted(args)
    return result
```

The issue is that it results in a nested list:

`biggest_gap(other_func(3))` # The use of the `other_func` does not matter, only that it creates a list of numbers

```
[[322,32,12]]
```

If I use the `sort()` method:

```
def biggest_gap(*args):
        result = args.sort()
        return result
```

returns:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'sort'
```

The question is how to stop the 'sorted' approach from creating a nested list and simply create a list or how to make the `sort()` method not throw an error.

Comment: Before testing `biggest_gap(other_func(3))`, I suggest testing `biggest_gap` on its own: try `biggest_gap(3,6,5)`, and `biggest_gap([3,6,5])`, to better understand what kind of argument is expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def biggest_gap(*args):
```

means that `args` will be *a list (well, technically a tuple) of all arguments* you gave to the `biggest_gap` function.

```
biggest_gap(other_func(3))
```

will give *a list* to the `biggest_gap` function. That's *one* argument.

So what you get is "a tuple of (a list)".

What you meant to do was giving a multiple individual arguments, by "splatting" the list returned from `other_func`:

```
biggest_gap(*other_func(3))
```

The difference the `*` makes is

```
biggest_gap([322, 32, 12])    # without * - biggest_gap receives 1 argument
biggest_gap(*[322, 32, 12])   # with * - biggest_gap receives 3 arguments
biggest_gap(322, 32, 12)      # hard-coded equivalent
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists

Comment: Nice approach, I never thought to "splat" a list like that. I was not aware of that operator; thanks for teaching me something new!

Comment: @Jerry good call with the tuple, I've updated that part in my answer.

Comment: Good point. From what you say, using *args in `biggest_gap`, is not the optimal way to do this after all/not needed. What way do you suggest?

Comment: @saZ It depends on how you look at it. `*args` is *the* standard way of creating [variadic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) in Python. You decide: Did you mean to write a function that takes any number of arguments? Use `biggest_gap(*args)`. Did you mean to write a function that a single argument (which is a list of values)? Use `biggest_gap(values)`. Python makes both options easy, which one better expresses your intention is your call.

Comment: Since the output of the previous function is a list, and the new function will in essence receive  this list ,I made like this: `def biggest_gap(x)` which takes the list as a single value. This is ok right?

Comment: @saZ Yes. This way you don't have to remember to use `*` every time you call `biggest_gap` with a list of values, which makes sense when that's the how you will call the function most of the time. (*"How will this function be called most of the time?"* is the main question to be answered when deciding whether `*args` is right thing or not.)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is a weird problem with *args in that it returns (in this case) a tuple of args assigned to the variable name **args**. So, for example, given a function:

```
def test(*args):
    return args
```

It will return:

```
>>> test("Hello", "World")
('Hello', 'World')
>>>
```

A tuple.
Then, sorted, this gets turned into a list.

So, now we can go back and help the original problem, as the nested list comes as a result of the function "other_function" returning a list of 3 numbers, say [1,23,44], and the function is then applied to it.

```
>>> sorted(test([1,23,44]))
[[1, 23, 44]]
>>>
```

NB: Tuples don't have a .sort method, instead an alternate method is to use the built in **sorted**() function.